# DC-DC converters and heat generation

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I've bought [this 12V to Magsafe 2 85W car adapter](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/402163982509) so I can charge my MacBook Pro off of my auxiliary batteries without having to keep the inverter on (more efficient). If I understand correctly, this is using a DC-DC step up converter to take the voltage from 10-14V up to 20V. The problem is it gets HOT, especially if the computer is under load. The charger's own internal temperature protection kicks in and it stops providing current until it cools off. Is this just because it's a cheap / defective product or because 7A is too much for a 12V cigarette lighter style outlet? Can I expect the same heat to be wasted if I build my own DC-DC converter as outlined by this [DIY article?](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2020/04/16/building-a-12v-dc-magsafe-charger/)

Some insights would be great, I just want to understand what's going on :)

UPDATE: I tried to build a heatsink for it that I stuck onto its metal back. It did not work. I took it apart and found that that the metal cap is connected to nothing internally explaining why the heat sink did not work. In addition, all of the electronics were encapsulated in foam, which I'm sure did not help with the overheating. I am now going to build my own like in the article linked but I have [another electrical question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509175/powering-two-19v-devices-from-a-single-12v-to-19v-converter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a MacBook Pro, the input power from the charger can be as high as 85W at 18.5VDC, which means about 4.6A input current drawn from the charger.

> or because 7A is too much for a 12V cigarette lighter style outlet?

The charger is most likely a DC-DC boost converter and assuming it's electrical efficiency is 92% at best, the input power should be 85 / 0.92 = 92.5W. The cigarette lighter's fuse is usually 10-15A, so ~120W output can be drawn safely.

The charger seems too tiny for an 85W converter. As there are no holes in the outer case for the air convection and it's hard to believe that there's a heatsink inside, a dissipation power of 92-85 = 7W can cause a lot of heat inside.

> Can I expect the same heat to be wasted if I build my own DC-DC converter as outlined by this DIY article?

The calculation is simple. You can expect at least a total of 10W power to be wasted by MOSFETs and inductors. So you should take the thermal considerations into account, and provide the required precautions for the hot air to be ventilated *(openings, heatsinks, copper areas, etc)*.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight. I didn't think 7-10W could cause that much heat, but I suppose even a 5W bulb does get hot if you hold onto it. I think you meant 4.6A *output* drawn form the charger, or about 6.5A into it (at ~13V of a lithium battery). It'd be cool to open it up and see how I can mod it so it can dissipate heat better.  The regular AC adapter doesn't get as hot even though it has no holes. Is that because its surface area is much larger?

Comment: @Flyview `The regular AC adapter doesn't get as hot even though it has no holes. Is that because its surface area is much larger?` Yes, and it has heatsinks for dissipative components inside (MOSFETs, rectifiers etc). Holes are often required for relatively smaller products. Besides, the car charger draws around 90W from the lighter, so the input current is around 8A; but the AC adapter draws the same power from grid, and the input current is even less than 1A. See the difference? The more the current flows through, the higher the dissipation.

Comment: Yes, it's bound to be all of the above. Although why would more current create more heat? Isn't it *power* that's relevant? It's less input current but at a higher voltage in the wall adapter.

Comment: @Flyview `Although why would more current create more heat? Isn't it power that's relevant?` From P = V x I, decreasing the input voltage increases the input current for the same power. In either buck or boost converters, the current flows through inductor and MOSFET during switching action. So, increasing the level of switching current increases the dissipation of those components. This is called "I²R losses", where R can be the DC resistance of an inductor or the drain-source resistance of a MOSFET.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. It's similar to how you need bigger wires to carry the same power at a lower voltage because of the higher current.

Comment: Please have a look at my update!

Answer (score 2):

At least it has thermal protection!

You should define "build my own." The DC-DC converter the guy uses in the article you posted says it is 96% efficient (I find that hard to believe, but eBay never lies!). You would be hard pressed to design anything that efficient while maintaining a budget. If you go the full DIY route, you can expect efficiencies of anywhere from 75-90%. Either way you're dissipating 85*0.25 = 20W worst case.

Lets say that the one you have now is pretty darn good and also is 96% efficient. It will dissipate ~3.4W. This power is dissipated throughout your board, in traces, in wires, in components, in everything, but most of it will come from your semiconductors (diodes, fets) and magnetics. I posted a snip from a random Vishay FET datasheet. A lot of components will have a thermal resistance from junction (the literal P-N junction of the die) to ambient air, or the case of the part. This is what determines how hot the parts get. You can dissipate 3.4W in something with 1 degC/W thermal resistance and have it get slightly warmer, or you could feed it through this FET and get a 90degree C rise!

[image: datasheet snip]

Of course, this is for a FET with no heatsink that isn't attached to a board or anything.

Thermal impedance works just like resistors. You can actually calculate temp rise at each junction like you would a voltage divider.

What I'm trying to get at is a power supply will only get as hot as you allow it to. If you don't care about size you could take the one you have apart and slap on bigger heatsinks, or even a fan.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight. I didn't think 5W could cause that much heat, but I suppose even a 5W bulb does get hot if you hold onto it. It'd be cool to open it up and see how I can mod it so it can dissipate heat better. The DIY method with the boost converter seems to have a pretty beefy heatsink on it whereas this cigarette lighter adapter has nothing. The regular AC adapter doesn't get as hot even though it has no holes. Is that because its surface area is much larger?