# Powering two 19v devices from a single 12V to 19V converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, 12v

I am building a laptop charger to run off of a 12V source (lithium batteries in a camper). Initially, I was just going to replicate [this article](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2020/04/16/building-a-12v-dc-magsafe-charger/) to make a 12V MagSafe 2 charger for my MacBook Pro (up to 85W). I bought a 12V male plug rated for 15A, and [this 12V to 19V converter](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07PDWTY5C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) rated for 8A output (152W). Would there be an issue if I also ran a 19V LG monitor (up to 40W) off of the same 19V output in addition to the MacBook Pro? Could connecting/disconnecting one cause a surge in voltage or current for the other?

UPDATE: I finished building this and so far so good, it works! I will update this with a DIY write up when I make it. Thanks for the confidence. It tested it on a really hot day, ambient temps at 30c. The wiring is at ambient temp and the converter is barely warm to the touch. The male 12V plug gets slightly warm but not hot at all. The system uses up 1W of power with nothing plugged in. The MagSafe tip does start to build heat if left unplugged. I suspect this is due to the converter always sending out 19V to the tip, even when not plugged into the MacBook. The AC charger only sends out 3V to the tip when unplugged.

Comment: SHOULD be safe, but Murphy can strike anywhere.  You could try giving the onverter an eg lightbulb load (note heavy turn on surge) and then add/remove a smaller secondary load to see how stable it was. || Potentially most likely place for a surge is when removing large load when a small load is still connected. Boost converter can have excess energy for one cycle BUT this should be small if  and only for one cycle if well designed.

Comment: A lot of the time, the potential problem with what people want to do relates to overheating which is hard to simulate/calculate because there are so many variables. My advice is to give it a try and see what happens, however, during the early stages, everything is "on probation." You need to watch for any part of the business to see if it gets hot. If not, then it is probably OK. Make sure that during probation you try to create worst-case conditions, such as maximum ambient temperature and maximum load.

Comment: Don't overlook that connectors and wires may get too hot. Not just the electronics themselves.

Comment: Both the MacBook and the monitor have (or are likely to have) internal step-downs and filtering, so you should be clear to do this. They are unlikely to back feed as well.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm worried because MacBooks are known to be sensitive and third party chargers have been known to cause damage to the current sensing circuit, although those are usually AC-DC third party chargers. Backed as in have the battery put out current towards the charger when unplugged? Absolutely, I will keep an eye on the temps.

Comment: Is your 15A plug a “cigarette lighter ” type plug? In my (boating) experience they (and their sockets) can’t be trusted for anything substantial, especially with currents above 10A.

Comment: @StarCat yes it is. Even at absolutely full load (125W) I am expecting to be at just about 10A draw from the socket so hopefully that part is okay but I will keep my eye on it. Worst comes to worst I can hardwire it with a switch.

Comment: As others have suggested, you may give it a try and see what happens (i.e. see if the converter's overtemp/overload protection kicks in or if the cigarette lighter's fuse goes blown). You should also provide the necessary environment for the converter's heatsink for better air convection (i.e. don't cover it). PS: I saw a lot of China-made converters that never provide the power-on-nameplate continuously. Chinese engineers tend to write peak (or even peak-to-peak) values. Hope yours is not one of those :)

Comment: @RohatKılıç Could I test how much it can provide with a voltmeter set on current? I'm also not expecting to pull 125W from it continuously. It will probably be more like 100W and it's rated for 152W! It's pretty beefy so I'm hoping it will dissipate heat nicely. Worst case scenario I have a small 12v fan I can put on it. I will update here when I finish the project. Do you see any concern as to one device affecting the other because they're run off of the same converter output? That was my main worry here.

Comment: No need to measure the load current. But you may measure the output voltage to see if it drops substantially as the load increases *(I'd expect a drop of less than 0.5V while both devices are working fully)*. If it drops too much (e.g. 3VDC) then your MacBook pro may stop charging. I don't think that one device may affect the other but, the output voltage drop is one thing to consider while both devices are drawing power from the converter.

Comment: @RohatKılıç no-brand stuff made in China for export is not always very high quality. I think the engineering talent in China is fine, but sometimes the management does not care, especially for export only goods that will not circulate within China. American (and other) consumers are willing to buy it if it is cheap enough and take their chances with the specifications.

Comment: @mkeith  Indeed - I note that a country that can send men to orbit and retrieve them alive is capable of most engineering feats*. But equally, if buyers demand lowest possible prices and are prepared to accept the inevitable drop in quality it is always possible to find willing sellers. [*India has not managed that yet, but are the only country to have ever placed a spacecraft in orbit around Mars on the first attempt].

Comment: Updated main post after I finished the build! It works!

Comment: Congrats! `The MagSafe tip does start to build heat if left unplugged.` how much heat?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I don't have a temp gun but it doesn't get too hot to touch. It's almost too hot to put my lips on it (lol) but even that is fine. I just have to remember to unplug the converter. This may also be due to the MagSafe 2 cable I used not being OEM. I cut it off that tiny plug-in converter.